# How to send a value in Database to Google analytics?

Tags: php, symfony, google-analytics

I manage web application which is made by Symfony2(PHP).
I measure some value in Database (for example, register User per a day) on management screen made by myself.

But I want to compare this value with data on Google analytics.
so I want to know how to send a value in database to Google analytics.

Comment: Curl is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Data Import section on Property level, in Admin menu. You can find various range of data, that can be imported into Analytics, and applied to your reports.

It's not clear from your post, if any of these would be a solution for you. The detailed description of this feature is available [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en&utm_id=ad).

Personally, I'd do it reversed, and collect GA data for my management screen via GA API, if I had a management screen already.

Comment: Data imports work for adding data to newly incoming hits. They do not work for data already collected (unless you habe GA 360 and use Query Time Imports) and cannot create new hits, so this is fairly limited.